# How to lock a realm for GM only?

Tags: azerothcore

How can I make a specific realm be accessible only by GMs?

In other words, from accounts that have an access higher than 0 (in `acore_auth.account_access` table)?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is setting the `allowedSecurityLevel` field for the realm in the `realmlist` table of the `acore_auth` database:

For example, to limit to accounts level `1` and higher to the realm with id `1`:

```sql
UPDATE `realmlist` SET `allowedSecurityLevel` = 1 WHERE `id` = 1;
```

For more info, check the documentation of the `realmlist` table:

https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/realmlist